# jQuery AJAX HTTP error codes not being picked up in Safari

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, safari

I'm using `jQuery.ajax()` to send data to my own PHP file for adding subscribers to a MailChimp list.  The Javascript looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
  data: params, // the data is working so here is just the variable I'm using
  error: function(response) {
    console.error($.parseJSON(response));
    // show some response text through DOM manipulation
  }, success: function (response) {
    console.log($.parseJSON(response));
    // show some response text through DOM manipulation 
  }
});
```

The PHP looks like this (at least just for the HTTP status code response):

```
// All my PHP code, which is working is above this
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result; // This is for the response text in the ajax call
http_response_code(intval(json_decode($result)->status)); // This should be sending a success code or triggering errors
```

On Chrome, if I get a good response (a HTTP status in the 200s), the `success` function will run.  If I trigger an error (in my testing, a HTTP status in the 400s), the `error` function will run.  All is good.

However, on Safari, whether it is a 200 or a 400 code, the `success` function runs.  There seems to be no detection in my Javascript of error codes when using the Safari browser.  How can I fix this?  Why is it different between Chrome and Safari?

In case it matters, I'm working locally with CodeKit and MAMP PRO to run my project.  Thanks.

Comment: It's odd at how the PHP works. I'd think the response code needs to be set before the response is sent. Otherwise you'd get a "headers already sent" error.

Comment: @apokryfos you genius!  Make that the answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the response code before the actual response, i.e.,

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
http_response_code(intval(json_decode($result)->status)); // This should be sending a success code or triggering errors
echo $result; // This is for the response text in the ajax call
```

This is because `http_response_code` is essentially running a `header("HTTP/1.0 $code $codeMessage")` and the `header` needs to be sent before the response.